# Creating and referencing class libraries with dotnet CLI and VSCode just like you can do in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

I want to start using vscode to develop .net core apps, but I am a bit confused about how to create class libraries as separate projects and reference them.

For example: In a Visual Studio Solution I would add a Web API project and then several class libraries to that solution. Right click the Web API project and Add Reference as necessary.

Can this same thing be done with VS Code and dotnet CLI even though there is no solution concept?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create Solution Folder

```
c:\Projects>mkdir SampleDotNet
c:\Projects>cd SampleDotNet
```

Create SampleDotNet solution

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet>dotnet new sln
```

Create src folder (optional)

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet>mkdir src 

c:\Projects\SampleDotNet>cd src
```

Create Web API Project

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet\src>dotnet new webapi -n SampleDotNet.Api
```

Create Class Library Project

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet\src>dotnet new classlib -n SampleDotNet.Services
```

**Reference Library Project to Web API Project**

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet\src>dotnet add SampleDotNet.Api/SampleDotNet.Api.csproj reference SampleDotNet.Services/SampleDotNet.Services.csproj
```

**Finally Add Projects to Solution**

```
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet\src>cd ..
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet>dotnet sln add src/SampleDotNet.Api/SampleDotNet.Api.csproj
c:\Projects\SampleDotNet>dotnet sln add src/SampleDotNet.Services/SampleDotNet.Services.csproj
```

### Commands

[image]

### Result

Visual Studio Code

[image]

Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Amazing response. Thank you so much!